# Mapping integers to Ed25519 and back again?

Tags: ed25519

I would like to map integer values to points on Ed25519, and then back again.

Is there a technique that takes advantage of the specific structure of Ed25519?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Elligator 2, but it has some limitations.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Thank you! This looks very promising.